# UI is wrong after keyboard is dismissed Flutter

Tags: flutter

I started with a scaffold that didn't slide up but got squeeze, and after a suggested answer I adapted it to use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,` and a `SingleChildScrollView` as the body and removed the `Expanded`
widget that was wrapping the second `Column`. Now that messed up the UI quite a bit. The firs Container only occupied 2/3 of the screen heigh, so after adjusting all paddings UI got back as before. The problem is the, dough when the keyboard appears the screen slides up, when the keyboard disappears the UI is a mess again. Can you see what's going wrong?

## original Scaffold:

```
Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
          body: Container(
            color: Colors.black54,
          key: widget.key,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 100, vertical: 30),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 2),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 15),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

## modified Scaffold:

```
Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true, // widgets still get squeezed
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black54,
              key: widget.key,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:50, right:50, top:30, bottom: 100),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 2),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 30),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                      ],
                    ),
                    //                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: `Scaffold(
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
              resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                child: Container(`                                                                                                   
            in this code try to remove `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),` @Vincenzo

Comment: Usually SingleChildScrollView will fix the issue@Vincenzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution:

1. set `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true`
2. remove first `Expanded`

Something like this:

```
 Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true, ** <- here **
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      [...]
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            //Expanded( ** <- here - remove this **
              //child: 
              Padding(
                [...]
              )
            //)
        ])
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been going mad with this for a couple of days.. I kinda understood that that Expanded was the cause..but when I tried removing it I was getting error as Rows in Column had an expanded widget. I guess that `SingleChildScrollView` in combination with  `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true` ( not `false` as I tried various suggested solutions ) fixed it. Again many many thanks. Cheers.

Comment: Actually using SingleChildScrollView messed up the UI. I then readjusted all padding values to obtain correct UI drawing again. Dough the view slides up when keyboard opens, after it closes the UI is  wrong quite a bit. Can you see what's going wrong? see updated question

Comment: Before opening the keyboard, try scrolling the screen, as I assume there is a space at the bottom of it.

Comment: Indeed.. when redoing the paddings to re obtain previous UI layout I actually thought that a 100 bottom in the first padding was wired.. but that was the value that gave me the correct UI.. Anyways.. thank you very much again

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the whole page with `SingleChildScrollView` should do the trick

Comment: Indeed I tried as my first two code samples show. Did I do it wrong? Can you provide a correct way of wrapping it?

Comment: Wrapping your whole `Scaffold` with `SingleChildScrollView` instead of only wrapping the body

Comment: hmm thats odd.. somehow i did something similar it worked for me, try this then remove `Scaffold` , use `SingleChildScrollView(child: Container(child: Column(children: [//your widgets here])))`

Comment: Nope..didn't work either. I added pics of the the view. I noticed that is the second column that gets contracted, as it it in an `Expanded` widget.

Comment: Im sorry i cant be of further help, i rarely touch Expanded widgets due to encountering errors with it often , but never your type so i thought i could help but unfortunately ;( Sorry